# JS, how to call a nameless list

Tags: javascript, json, list, parsing

I am attempting to parse and retrieve data from an API, but it seems that there is a list that has no name assigned to it, making it impossible for me to call the values within. Here is a masked and run down example of what I am referring to.

(This is the json)

```
{
"numberOne": [
    {
        (other information would be in here)
    }
]
}
```

As you can see. number one has a list within itself, which then contains the "other information. The thing is, I cannot send a path to it in javascript (with my method) as I can't simply do  convertedJson.numberOne.?.otherInformationValue

Does anyone know how something like this would be done?

Thanks :)

Comment: It's array `convertedJson.numberOne[0]`

Comment: Example: `{numberOne: [{a:12}, {a:13}]}`, do you want get result: [12, 13]?

Comment: what do you mean by "the list is nameless"? In the example you provided, the name of the list is "numberOne"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the list in your example is `numberOne`.
You can access the objects in the list using their index:

```
exampleJSON = {
    "numberOne": [
        {
            "num1" : "value1"
        },
        {
            "num2" : "value2"
        },
    ]
}

let value1 = exampleJSON.numberOne[0].num1;
let value2 = exampleJSON.numberOne[1].num2;
//...etc
```

Comment: Thanks! Also thanks to the people above, it all helped :)